# How to aim and shoot with pistol in Assassins Creed 4?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

I am playing Assassins Creed 4 on PC but I don't know how to aim and shoot with the pistol. What keys do I press to use the pistol?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the tutorial? When you open the pause menu, go to `Database > Tutorials` and look for the point `Pistols`. If it's greyed out, that means you can't use pistols yet; if it's _not_ greyed out, just launch the tutorial and it'll teach you how to shoot.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have Pistols selected, by hitting "4". Then make sure they are reloaded, hit "R"
Make sure you have Bullets, should be a number other then 0 by the pistol Icon.

Now you are good to go, Press and hold the "Right Mouse Button" to aim, use your mouse to move your crosshairs. click "Left Mouse Button" to fire. You can also auto fire at a highlighted target by pressing "f"

Answer (score 0):

Click button''4''and select your target by holding the ''right mouse button'' after selecting the target press the ''left mouse button'' to shoot the pistol.